# GCP Gen2 Cloud Function Terraform Event Arc Trigger Creating PubSub Topic Error

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-pubsub, terraform-provider-gcp, event-arc

I am trying to create an event-driven Cloud Function via gen2 terraform utilizing the auditlog event type. Essentially, I would like to trigger the function each time a GCP secret is created.

Following this [documentation] https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/cloudfunctions2_function#example-usage---cloudfunctions2-basic-auditlogs , my code looks as such:

```
resource "google_cloudfunctions2_function" "function" {
  for_each = toset(var.gcp_locations)

  location    = each.value
  project     = var.project_id
  name        = var.function_name
  description = "test!"

  build_config {
    runtime     = "python311"
    entry_point = "entry_point"
    environment_variables = {
      HTTP_PROXY  = "xxxx",
      HTTPS_PROXY = "xxxx",
      NO_PROXY    = "grc.io,pkg.dev"
    }
    source {
      storage_source {
        bucket = google_storage_bucket.code_bucket[each.value].name
        object = google_storage_bucket_object.code_object[each.value].name
      }
    }
    worker_pool = google_cloudbuild_worker_pool.pool[each.value].id
  }

  service_config {
    max_instance_count             = 3
    min_instance_count             = 1
    available_memory               = "4Gi"
    timeout_seconds                = 60
    ingress_settings               = "ALLOW_INTERNAL_AND_GCLB"
    vpc_connector                  = var.serverless_conn[format("%s-%s", var.environment, each.value)]
    vpc_connector_egress_settings  = "PRIVATE_RANGES_ONLY"
    all_traffic_on_latest_revision = true
    service_account_email          = var.sa_email
  }
  event_trigger {
    trigger_region        = "us-east4"
    event_type            = "google.cloud.audit.log.v1.written"
    retry_policy          = "RETRY_POLICY_RETRY"
    service_account_email = google_service_account.trigger.email
    event_filters {
      attribute = "serviceName"
      value = "secretmanager.googleapis.com"
    }
    event_filters {
        attribute = "methodName"
        value = "secretmanager.secrets.create"
    }
    event_filters {
      attribute = "resourceName"
      value = "projects/_/secrets/_"
      operator = "match-path-pattern" # This allows path patterns to be used in the value field
    }

  }


}
```

Focusing on the "event trigger" section. When I try to apply this, it appears GCP tries to create a PubSub Topic in the background, and we have organization policy in place to block anything non CMEK encrypted. I do not understand why GCP is trying to spin a pubsub topic named ``? This is the error message

```
│ Error: Error waiting to create function: Error waiting for Creating function: Error code 9, message: Creating trigger failed for projects/<PROJECT_ID>/locations/us-east4/triggers/secret-checker-077177: generic::failed_precondition: Constraint `constraints/gcp.restrictNonCmekServices` violated for `projects/<PROJECT_ID>` attempting to set the kms_key_name for a Pub/Sub topic to ``.
```

Despite this not making any sense per the documentation, I try to spin the function with an CMEK encrypted pubsub topic, and then I get this error :

```
Error: Error creating function: googleapi: Error 400: Pubsub topic can only be set for events with type google.cloud.pubsub.topic.v1.messagePublished.
```

Really confused on why it the provider would try to spin a pubsub topic, and then when I try to add a pubsub, it yells at me for the incorrect event type?

Any help appreciated! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because, when using this event type, GCP actually spins a pubsub topic on your behalf. As a result of this, I an unable to encrypt it with my companies cmek key.

Simply, this is not possible to do with this org policy in place.